# Error creating Uri object

Tags: java, android, uri

Every time I create an `Uri` object as new `Uri("some uri")` it says an Uri cannot instantiate. Is there any other solution?

```
Uri u = new Uri("content://contacts");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
  Uri.parse("link/here");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29